# Unsupervised classification (clustering) for continuous human activity accelerometer

Tags: machine-learning, accelerometer

I have accelerometer data (X,Y,Z) during a continuous bout of exercises. What is the most effective way of clustering the data into it's given exercise as shown in the figure? I.e. unsupervised classification of transition/rest, squats, lunges, walk, biceps curls, and shoulder press.

I've used k-means before but that required me to cut the sample into epochs and complete descriptive statistics (mean, range, etc) for each epoch, which I would like to avoid so the epochs don't necessarily align with the beginning of the movement.

In the end I want to be able to run through accelerometer data and identify how long/how many exercises the user completed.

[image]

Comment: Are you clustering or classifying? Do you want to classify signals as either squats, walking etc, or do you want to cluster them into exercise time periods?

Comment: @Neil From my understanding, unsupervised classification is analogous to clustering. Thus, I want to classify the periods of the unlabeled signal into squats, walking, etc. but since it's not possible for me to label all of the data, I want to create clusters.

Comment: Yea the reason I asked whether you are clustering or classifying is that classification should usually be supervised. It will be very tricky to get a clustering (unsupervised) algorithm to come up with exactly those categories that you want.

Comment: If it's continuous data you will also have to divide it into some sort of 'batches'. You can make these quite small. But I don't see how you can classify infinitely many points.

Comment: Have you put any of the signal into the frequency domain?

Comment: Yes, using k-means clusters works decently well when using the epochs but as I mentioned, having to create these epochs is not ideal because they don't perfectly align with movement starts and ends. That's why I'm curious to see if there is a way without windowing

Comment: I'm not sure what the best solve is. But based the graph, it looks like frequency and amplitude of 2 or 3 waves should be enough to figure out what it is. So divide it into lots of little groups of 2 or three waves and get the average frequency and amplitude of the batch. If you really want perfection, write an algorithm that re-slices batches that fall on the margins by cutting them elsewhere (use anomaly detection for that). Then I'd label a couple of points manually, and give the data to a decision tree. Then give the trained tree some unlabelled data and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Both clustering and classification relies on having a set of features with suitable information to predict the underlying class.
For time-series data the standard method is bag-of-frames, chopping it up into small (overlapping) chunks called frames. The frame lengths should be considerably shorter than the minimum timespan of a class it is desirable to detect, but must be long enough to capture relevant characteristics.
In exercise data it should maybe have time for N reps, say on the order of 5 seconds. These frames will not, and don't need to, align with your activities.

When activities change, in a well trained model, the probability for all the classes should be low, so simply avoid outputting the prediction in that case. If this is not enough you can use a majority: require that N (maybe 3) consecutive frames are classified the same way to output it as a true prediction.

If the bag-of-frames approach is not enough, then consider using Dynamic Time Warping (DTW).

Comment: Hi @jonnor. Thanks for the reply. I did end up binning the data and it worked quite well when they were exercising but poorly during rest/transition. I like the idea of having to be consecutive clusters so I will play around with adding a post-hoc criterion. 

Thank you also for the suggestion of Dynamic Time Warping. I'll look into it as well.

Comment: If you do not have it yet, consider adding a class for resting. You may want to also add a simple feature like energy or RMS to help isolate this class. One can also use a dedicated 'activity/no activity' detector followed by exercise classification (cascade), but try the simple thing first

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I ran across [link to paper](https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210x.13605) called "The Purr-fect Catch: Using accelerometers and audio recorders to document kill rates and hunting behaviour of a small prey specialist".

They classified lynx activity with accelerometers using both a 1-d CNN and a RandomForest using "tsfresh" features. Selecting a window size that fit within the activities and then after prediction, clumping them together into the full events.  Apparently, the RandomForest did better than the CNN.

Might be helpful.